# How to tell if List A, with a discrete number of repeated elements, is contained in List B?

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list of letters, L[], and I would like to run through a master list of words and only return words that are composed of the letters in L.

The letters in L can be only repeated some specific number of times (think drawing Scrabble letters), which is to say that...

```
['a', 'e', 't']
['a', 'e', 'e', 't']
['a', 'e', 'e', 'e', 't']
```

...are three different, valid lists.

If the operation were given

```
L = ['a', 'e', 't']
```

and a dictionary of words to run through, it **would** match

```
a
at
ate
eat
tea
ta
...
```

but **would not** match

```
aa
atta
tata
tate
tet
...
```

I can't use

```
set(W).issubset(L)
```

because of the repeated letters, and I can't use

```
all(x in L for x in W)
```

because that will match an unlimited number of repeats.

I thought about either pop()ing every element in L that matches one in W, or numbering subsequent occurrences of a letter, like

```
    ['a', 'a1', 'a2', 'e', 'e1', 't']
```

to be able to use sets, but I wondered if there was a simpler way I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

Since subtraction of [Counters](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) only keeps positive counts

```
from collections import Counter
not(Counter(W) - Counter(L))
```

eg:

```
>>> not(Counter('a') - Counter('aet'))
True
>>> not(Counter('ate') - Counter('aet'))
True
>>> not(Counter('tea') - Counter('aet'))
True
>>> not(Counter('aa') - Counter('aet'))
False
>>> not(Counter('tata') - Counter('aet'))
False
>>> not(Counter('tet') - Counter('aet'))
False
```

Of course `L` can be any sequence of items - `list`, `set`, etc.

Comment: This is not correct.  `Counter('a') <= Counter('bcd')` is true although "a" is not a possible word made from the letters "bcd".  The less-than operator for Counter only takes account of the number of objects.

Comment: Oh winrar! I am not familiar with Counter, but had seen it referenced in other list questions. I hadn't thought of testing for the failure condition of trying to remove all of L from W. Thanks!

Comment: And I see you've expanded your answer with more explanatory text, many thanks for that as well. (And I just looked at your profile -- ~3K answers! I am in awe.)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
def possible(letters, word):
    available = collections.Counter(letters)
    present = collections.Counter(word)
    return all(present[let] <= available[let] for let in present)
```

Comment: `Counter` has comparison operators defined.

Comment: @Tim: It does, but they don't do what this problem requires, as far as I can see.